# Jquery Datatables plugin CSS defaults not being applied. Pagination and search appear on the left side of the table. and without styles

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, displaytag

I have a tables which was previously using displaytags. I decided to move the pagination to the browser so it can be fast. I used datatables jquery plugin for this. But the pagination, Search etc are F***** up. im trying to resolve it since a day and now i dont have much time left. Please tell me whats causing it. Below is the Datatable and Display tags and some images of the result.

datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cmpReport').DataTable({
        "bAutoWidth" : false,
        "aoColumns" : [ {
            sWidth : '1%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '8%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '8%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '5%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '3%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '11%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '3%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '7%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '7%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '5%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '5%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '5%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '7%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '5%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '5%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '5%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '5%'
        }, {
            sWidth : '5%'
        } ]
    });
});
```

Display tags:

```
<display:table htmlId="cmpReport" id="cmpReport" name="cmpReport" sort="external" partialList="true" size="bigSize" pagesize="${bSize}" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; white-space: normal !important;" class="thinBorder stripe row-border    compact cell-border td.dt-center"
            requestURI="/CmpReportAction.do" export="false">
            <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="none" />
            <%-- <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.group_size" value="5" /> --%>
            <display:setProperty name="css.tr.even" value="dataWh" />
            <display:setProperty name="css.tr.odd" value="coldata" />
            <%-- <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="cmpReport.csv" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="cmpReport.xls" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="cmpReport.pdf" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="cmpReport.xml" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.csv.include_header" value="true" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.excel.include_header" value="true" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.include_header" value="true" /> --%>
            <display:column headerClass="tableHead" title=" " style="text-align:center" media="html">
                <img class="expand" alt="" src="images/plus.jpg" onclick="toggleHawbInfo(this.parentNode.parentNode)" />
            </display:column>
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="MBL" property="mblno" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxMLB" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="HAWB" property="hblno" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxHawb" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Compliance" property="compliance" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Total<br> Scanned<br> Docs" property="totalScanned" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxTSD" maxLength="10" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="STT" property="stt" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxSTT" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Product" property="product" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxProd" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Ship#" property="archive_Num" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxShip" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Ship date" property="shpmt_create_date" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" maxLength="10" class="ajaxShipDt" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Ship NAD" property="shpr_id" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxShipNad" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Ship Name" property="shipper" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" maxLength="10" class="ajaxShipName" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Cons NAD" property="csgn_id" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxConsNad" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Cons Name" property="consignee" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxCons" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Pay Term" property="service_type" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxPay" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Inco Term" property="inco_terms" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxInco" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Dep" property="org" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxDep" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Destination" property="des" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxDest" />
            <display:column headerClass="repsub" title="Service Level" property="serv_lvl_code" style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center;" sortable="false" class="ajaxSL" maxLength="10" />
        </display:table>
```

Now a pic of the final result.
[image]

Edit: The divs containing the search and pagination buttons have the below attributes.

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="cmpReport_paginate">
```

Previous12345…93Next

```
<div id="cmpReport_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
```

Search:

Comment: Best to right click on them and inspect the elements on the browser. Looks like the container(s) that wrap those have the wrong width.

Comment: I right clicked and checked the css classes being applied. They have the right names. Added them to the question for reference

Comment: whats the css width set of the container(s). while inspecting click the HTML that contains them , it should blue highlight them in the browser. and then check the css and find the width

Comment: the div containing the table along with search, pagination and show "10" results options is 1140 Px lenght and 454 px height. For each individual container inside it, the length is 1140

Comment: so that means they dont fit on the screen. try putting a <br /> break line in between and see if that helps. Is your site live so i can have a look?

Comment: its live within the company network. i tried the <br> but it just adds another line of space.

Answer (score 2):

Alright.. guys.. i made a blunder.. the data tables css that came along with data tables was in a folder called datatables/css and i had it wrong. getting it right fixed the issue for me.